# Using the Grails Resources plugin, how do I load a Javascript file based on the user's locale?

Tags: grails, localization, internationalization, grails-2.0

I'm using the Grails Resources plugin with jQuery validation. jQuery validation has locale-specific texts declared as JS files:

```
/localization
    messages_ar.js
    messages_bg.js
    messages_ca.js
```

And so on and so forth. In my `ApplicationResources.groovy` file, I have the following block declared:

```
form {
    resource url: '/js/jquery/jquery.validate.js'
    resource url: '/js/jquery/jquery.validate.additional-methods.js'
    resource url: '/js/jquery/localization/messages_es.js'
}
```

But this is a hard-coded value. Is there any way I can configure the Resources plugin to load the correct JS file based on the user's locale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I've done this in the past:

- Define some foreign bundles and end them with the accept-language header (e.g. messages_en.js or messages_es.js)
- In your view when you are laying out resources, add something like:

  <r:external uri="js/messages_${RequestContextUtils.getLocale(request).getLanguage()}.js"/>

this should properly pull the resource based on the local.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi Johnny, thanks for the answer. The issue I have here is that the `messages_xx.js` file depends on jQuery validation getting loaded first, and I don't have it on every page (just the ones that have forms). Is there a way to configure `<r:external>` to only include a JS file if a certain module is included?

Comment: I don't believe so. However, you could 1. Cat the validation plugin as to your JQuery minified version (remember, this should only be downloaded once and then cached in the browser), 2. Cat the messages* file with the validation plugin (again; downloaded once although less efficient than the previous IMO) or 3. Manually include the plugin on the pages that have the message* files. Hope this helps!